# React Div Refuses to Display

Tags: reactjs

I have a div that refuses to display. It is the div called "NotificationsContainer". The test text "abcde" that is in inside the div refuses to display. NotificationsContainer contains the NotificationsDropdown component. This is identical to the MessagesDropdown component (I am making a copy of Facebook) that is present in the lines of code below it in the Navigation component, which contains both the NotificationsDropdown and MessageDropdown components. However, the MessagesDropdown component works and the NotificationsDropdown component does not display---even the test text "abcde" inside its parent div "NotificationsContainer" refuses to display, despite it being set to display:block. Here is the code:

Navigation Component

```
import React, {Component}  from "react";
import jsxToString from 'jsx-to-string';
import { NavLink, render } from "react-router-dom";
import '../css/headerstyle.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import CreatePost from "./CreatePost";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { transitions, positions, Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert'

import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'
import OutsideAlerter from "./OutsideAlerter";
import MessagesDropdown from "./MessagesDropdown";
import NotificationsDropdown from "./NotificationsDropdown";
import {ReactSession} from 'react-client-session';

class Navigation extends Component {



  
  constructor(props) {
    

    super(props);

    this.onClickCreatePost = this.onClickCreatePost.bind(this);
    this.createPostIsVisible = false;

    this._isMounted = false;

    
    this.state = {
      error: null,
     


      showCreatePost: false,
      showNotifications: false,
      

      mySearchBrowsePeople: undefined,
      searchBrowsePeopleInputValue: "",
      showMessagesDropdown: false,
      showNotificationsDropdown: false
    };
    
    this.getMessagesNumber = this.getMessagesNumber.bind(this);

    this.showHideComponent = this.showHideComponent.bind(this);
    

    
    this.showMessagesDropdownHandler = this.showMessagesDropdownHandler.bind(this);
    this.showNotificationsDropdownHandler = this.showNotificationsDropdownHandler.bind(this);
    this.render = this.render.bind(this);
  }

  searchBrowsePeople = async val => {
    console.log("entered searchbrowsepeople");
    this.setState({ loadingSearchBrowsePeople: true });

    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("search", this.state.searchBrowsePeopleInputValue);


    const res = await axios.post("http://localhost/api/getsearch.php", params);
    
    
    
    const mySearchBrowsePeople = await res.data;
    console.log("1" + mySearchBrowsePeople);
    console.log("2" + JSON.stringify(mySearchBrowsePeople));
    this.setState({ mySearchBrowsePeople: mySearchBrowsePeople, loadingSearchBrowsePeople: false });
  };
  
  onChangeSearchBrowsePeopleHandler = async e => {
    this.searchBrowsePeople(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ searchBrowsePeopleInputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  

  onClickCreatePost(){
    this.createPostIsVisible = !(this.createPostIsVisible);
  }
  
  


  showHideComponent(e) {
    console.log(e);
    switch (e) {
      case "CreatePost":
        this.setState({ showCreatePost: !this.state.showCreatePost });
        console.log("line 45 showCreatePost " + this.state.showCreatePost)
        this.props.onChangeParentStyle();
        break;
      case "MessagesDropdown":
          this.setState({ showMessagesDropdown: !this.state.showMessagesDropdown });
          
          break;
      case "NotificationsDropdown":
        this.setState({ showNotificationsDropdown: !this.state.showNotificationsDropdown });
        
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.render();
  }

  async getMessagesNumber(){
    console.log("entered getMessagesnumber");
     let data = await axios
      .get("http://localhost/api/headerGetNewMessagesNumber.php")
      .then(res => {
        return res;
        
      })

      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("error: " + error)

        this._isMounted && this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error: error
        });
        
      });
  


  
  console.log("DATA: " + data);
  console.log("DATA2: " + JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log("DATA3: " + data.data);
  console.log("DATA4: " + JSON.stringify(data.data));
  


  let data2 = await axios
 .get("http://localhost/api/headerGetNewNotificationsNumber.php")
 .then(res => {
   return res;
   
})
 
 .catch(function(error) {
   console.log("error: " + error)

   this._isMounted && this.setState({
     isLoaded: true,
     error: error
   });
   
 });
 console.log("DATA3Notifications: " + data2.data);
 console.log("DATA4Notifications: " + JSON.stringify(data2.data));

console.log("am I mounted?" + this._isMounted);





 this._isMounted && this.setState({
  myNumberOfMessagesArray: data.data,
  myNumberOfNewNotificationsArray: data2.data,


});
  
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._isMounted = false;

}

 componentDidMount() {
 

  this._isMounted = true;
  

  console.log("entered componentDidMount: ")
  this.getMessagesNumber();
}
  
renderSearchBrowsePeople() {

  
  var searchBrowsePeople = <h1>There are no people</h1>;
  
  if (this.state.mySearchBrowsePeople) {
    searchBrowsePeople = <MainHeaderSearchResult list={this.state.mySearchBrowsePeople} />;
    
    console.log("inside if: " + jsxToString(searchBrowsePeople));
    
    //ADD THIS BACK ::: return new OutsideAlerter({searchBrowsePeople}).render();

    //myProp={<div><SomeComponent>Some String</div>}
  }
  console.log("after if: " + jsxToString(searchBrowsePeople));
  return searchBrowsePeople;


}

  render()
  
  {
    
    
    const {  error, myNumberOfMessagesArray, myNumberOfNewNotificationsArray,
      showCreatePost, showNotifications, mySearchBrowsePeople, searchBrowsePeopleInputValue, showMessagesDropdown, showNotificationsDropdown  } = this.state;
    console.log("line 215 showCreatePost " + showCreatePost);
    console.log("myNumberOfMessagesArray:" + myNumberOfMessagesArray);
    console.log("myNumberOfMessagesArray:" + JSON.stringify(myNumberOfMessagesArray));
    console.log("rerendering, and showMessagesDropdown is equal to: " + showMessagesDropdown)

    console.log("rerendering, and showNotificationsDropdown is equal to: " + showNotificationsDropdown)
  
      return (<div>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <title>YK Social Network</title>
        <meta name="description" content="My Profile" />
        <meta name="author" content="YK Social Network" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/headerstyle.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/profilepostsstyle.css" />
        <iframe name="hidden-iframe" style={{ display: 'none' }} />
        <div id="HeaderContainer">
          <div id="HeaderLogoBox">
            <a href="newsfeed.php">
              <img src="images/facebook.png" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="HeaderSearchBox">
            Search:
            {/*Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:*/}
            {/*<form autocomplete="off" action="/browsepeople.php">*/}
            <div id="Autocomplete">
              <input type="text" id="HeaderSearchFriends" name="HeaderSearchFriends" 
              
              
              value={this.state.searchBrowsePeopleInputValue}
              onChange={e => this.onChangeSearchBrowsePeopleHandler(e)}
              />
              <div id="SearchResultContainer">
                


                
                    {this.renderSearchBrowsePeople()
                    
                   }

                
              </div>
              {/*<input id="myInput" type="text" name="mySear" placeholder="Country">*/}
            </div>
            {/*<input type="submit">*/}
            {/*</form>*/}
          </div>
          <div id="HeaderBrowsePeopleBox">
            <a href="browsepeople.php">Browse People</a>
          </div>
          <div id="HeaderIconsBox">
            <a href="myprofile.php">
              <div id="HeaderProfilePhotoBox">
                <img src="<?php echo $profile_src; ?>" />
                &nbsp;
                {ReactSession.get("firstname")}
              </div>
            </a>
            <button ></button>
            <div className="IconBox" onClick={() => this.showHideComponent("CreatePost")} /**, <?php echo $myID; ?>, '<?php echo $firstname ?> */>
              <img src="images/plus2.png" />
            </div>
            <a onClick={() => this.showHideComponent("MessagesDropdown")}>
              <div className="IconBox" id="MessageIcon">
                    <img src="images/message2.png" />
                    {myNumberOfMessagesArray && myNumberOfMessagesArray.map(newItem => 
                      <>
                        
                        <div id="NewMessagesNumber" key = {newItem.id} style={{ display: newItem.numNewMessages > 0 ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
                          
                          {newItem.numNewMessages}
                        </div>
                      </>
        )}

              </div>
            
            </a>
        <a onClick={() => this.showHideComponent("NotificationsDropdown")}>
        <div className="IconBox" id="NotificationsIconBox" >
                <img src="images/notification.png" />
                {myNumberOfNewNotificationsArray && myNumberOfNewNotificationsArray.map(newItem => (
                      <>
                        <div id="NewNotificationsNumber" key = {newItem.id} style={{ display: newItem.numNewNotifications > 0 ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
                          {newItem.numNewNotifications}
                        </div>
                      </>
                    ))}
        </div>
        </a>
        <div className="IconBox" id="LogoutIconBox">
          <img src="images/down-arrow.png" />
          <div id="ChangePasswordDiv">Change Password</div>
          <div id="LogoutDiv">Log Out</div>
        </div>
        <div id="NotificationsContainer">
          abcde
          {showNotificationsDropdown && <NotificationsDropdown showHandler = {this.showNotificationsDropdownHandler}/>}
        </div>
        <div id="HeaderMessagesContainer">
          bcd
          {showMessagesDropdown && <MessagesDropdown showHandler = {this.showMessagesDropdownHandler}/>}
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
        
      {showCreatePost && <CreatePost />}
        
        
        


      </div>
      <div id="OpaqueDiv">
        &nbsp;     
      </div>
       
      


    </div>)

      
}

showMessagesDropdownHandler(){
  this.setState({ showMessagesDropdown: true });
  this.render();
}

showNotificationsDropdownHandler(){
  this.setState({ showNotificationsDropdown: true });
  console.log("in showNotificationsDropdownHandler and about to render");
  this.render();
}

changeParentToGray() {
  this.props.onChangeParentStyle('red');
}






onClick() {
  this.props.onChangeParentStyle();
}

  //return <span onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} style={{background: 'white', cursor: 'pointer'}}>
  //    Change parent style
  //</span>

onClickCreatePost(){

}

//$("#HeaderSearchFriends").keyup(function(){




}

export function MainHeaderSearchResult(props){
  console.log("mainheadersearchresult: " + JSON.stringify((props)));
  
  const toReturn = props.list.map((oneSearchResult) =>
      <li className = 'DynamicPerson' key={oneSearchResult.id} value={oneSearchResult.id}>
        <img src = {oneSearchResult.profilephotopath} />
        <span className = 'MyText'>{oneSearchResult.name}</span>
      </li>
  );
  
  return (
    <ul id = "SearchResult">{toReturn}</ul>
  );
}




export default Navigation;

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318643/how-to-change-parent-component-style-element-according-to-its-child-component-st
```

NotificationsDropdown.jsx:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../css/headerstyle.css';
import {ReactSession} from 'react-client-session';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class NotificationsDropdown extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
    

        super(props);
        this.render = this.render.bind(this);
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
        this.state = { myDropdownNotifications: undefined, loading: true};
        this.loadAndDisplayData = this.loadAndDisplayData.bind(this);
        
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        this.loadAndDisplayData();
        
    }

    async loadAndDisplayData(){
        var params = new URLSearchParams();
        console.log("ReactSession ID:" + ReactSession.get("id"));
        console.log("time is:" + new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ') + ":");
        params.append("userid", ReactSession.get("id"));
        params.append("oldestNotificationTimestampSoFar", new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' '));
        
        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost/api/getNotificationsDropdown.php", params);
    
        const myDropdownNotifications = await res.data;
        console.log("1" + myDropdownNotifications);
        console.log("2" + JSON.stringify(myDropdownNotifications));
        this.setState ({ myDropdownNotifications: myDropdownNotifications, loading: false});
        this.props.showHandler();
    }


  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.handleChange(e.target.value);
  }

 

  render() {
    const styles = {
        width:'360px',
        height:'500px',
        position:'absolute',
        top:'50px',
        left:'-60px',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        zIndex:'9999999999999999999999',
        display:'block',
        overflow: 'scroll'
      };

      
                   console.log("rerender in notificationsdropdown: " + JSON.stringify(this.state.myDropdownNotifications)); 
                   this.state.myDropdownNotifications && console.log("DID THIS!");  
                             
    //}
  return (
        
        <>
        <div id = "NotificationsTitle">

        Notifications

        </div>
        
        {this.state.myDropdownNotifications && this.state.myDropdownNotifications.map((oneNotification) =>
                                     
                                           // {/*let blueDotDisplay = false;
                                               // if (oneNotification.hasBeenViewed = "false"){
                                               //     blueDotDisplay = true;
                                                //}*/
                                            //}
                                            <>
                                           

                                            <div className = "OneNotification" id={'OneNotification' + oneNotification.userid}> 

                                                  
                                                  <img src={oneNotification.profilephotopath} className='OneNotificationProfilePic' />
                                                  <div className="OneNotificationRightDiv">
                                                      
                                                      <div className="OneNotificationInfo">
                                                      <div className="OneNotificationNameDiv">
                                                          {oneNotification.firstname + " " + oneNotification.lastname}
                                                      </div>
                                                      
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div className="OneNotificationDiv">
                                                      {decodeURI(<notificationMessage data = {oneNotification} />)}
                                                      
                                                      </div>
                                                  </div>
                                          
                                                  <div display = {(oneNotification.wasviewed == 'false') ? 'block' : 'none'} className="OneNotificationBlueDot" id={'OneNotificationBlueDot' + oneNotification.userid}>
                                                  </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                     )}
                        
                    
        </>
        )
  }


  notificationMessage(props) {
    const message = props.data.message;
    var myID = ReactSession.get("id");

    if (message =='friend_request'){
        return ' sent you a friend request.';
    }
    else if (message == 'friend_accepted'){
        return ' accepted your friend request.';
    }
    else if (message == "post_on_wall" && props.data.posterid != myID) {
      if (props.data.posteeid == myID){
          return ' posted on your wall.';
      }
      else if (props.data.posterid == props.data.posteeid){
          return ' posted an update.';
      }
      else {
          return ' posted on ' + props.data.firstname + ' ' + props.data.lastname + '\'s wall.';
      }
    }
    else if (message == "tagged_in_post") {
      return ' tagged you in a post.';
    }
    else if (message == "user_liked_post") {
      return' liked your post.';
    }
    else if (message == "user_liked_comment") {
      return ' liked your comment.';
    }
    else if (message == "commented_on_post") {
      return ' commented on your post.';
    }
}


}
```

MessagesDropdown.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../css/headerstyle.css';
import {ReactSession} from 'react-client-session';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class NewMessagesDropdown extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
    

        super(props);
        this.render = this.render.bind(this);
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
        this.state = { myDropdownMessages: undefined, loading: true};
        this.loadAndDisplayData = this.loadAndDisplayData.bind(this);
        
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        this.loadAndDisplayData();
        
    }

    async loadAndDisplayData(){
        var params = new URLSearchParams();
        console.log("ReactSession ID:" + ReactSession.get("id"));
        params.append("userid", ReactSession.get("id"));

        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost/api/getMessagesDropdown.php", params);
    
        const myDropdownMessages = await res.data;
        console.log("1" + myDropdownMessages);
        console.log("2" + JSON.stringify(myDropdownMessages));
        this.setState ({ myDropdownMessages: myDropdownMessages, loading: false});
        this.props.showHandler();
    }


  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.handleChange(e.target.value);
  }

 

  render() {
    const styles = {
        width:'360px',
        height:'500px',
        position:'absolute',
        top:'50px',
        left:'-60px',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        zIndex:'9999999999999999999999',
        display:'block',
        overflow: 'scroll'
      };

      
                   console.log("rerender: " + JSON.stringify(this.state.myDropdownMessages)); 
                   this.state.myDropdownMessages && console.log("DID THIS!");  
                             
    //}
  return (

        <>
        <div id = "HeaderMessagesTitle">

        Messenger

        </div>
        
        {this.state.myDropdownMessages && this.state.myDropdownMessages.map((oneMessage) =>
                                     
                                           // {/*let blueDotDisplay = false;
                                               // if (oneMessage.hasBeenViewed = "false"){
                                               //     blueDotDisplay = true;
                                                //}*/
                                            //}
                                            <>
                                            

                                            <div className = "OneHeaderMessage" id={'OneHeaderMessage' + oneMessage.userid}> 

                                                  
                                                  <img src={oneMessage.profilephotopath} className='OneHeaderMessageProfilePic' />
                                                  <div className="OneHeaderMessageRightDiv">
                                                      
                                                      <div className="OneHeaderMessageInfo">
                                                      <div className="OneHeaderMessageNameDiv">
                                                          {oneMessage.firstname + " " + oneMessage.lastname}
                                                      </div>
                                                      
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div className="OneHeaderMessageDiv">
                                                      {decodeURI(oneMessage.message)}
                                                      
                                                      </div>
                                                  </div>
                                          
                                                  <div display = {(oneMessage.wasviewed == 'false') ? 'block' : 'none'} className="OneHeaderMessageBlueDot" id={'OneHeaderMessageBlueDot' + oneMessage.userid}>
                                                  </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                     )}
                        
                    
        </>
        )
  }
}
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code for a question about a single element. Please see [ask] and consider paring your post down to just what's relevant.

Comment: A lot of code - Have you inspected the rendered HTML output? Maybe it is there but only hidden. If the `div`  that wraps `NotificationsContainer` is not visible at all (as you said, the text `abcde` is not visible), this is the first place I'd check.

Comment: Thank you, that is good advice